# Tabla dinamica react api

Tags: reactjs, materialize, react-axios

Tengo una tabla dinamica en la cual tengo un boton con el que se abre un modal y se debe enviar una url.
mi problema es que cuando doy clik en el boton para abrir el modal me envia siempre la misma url no la de cada item.

mi tabla es asi:

```
<tbody >
                {
                    (()=>{
                        if (this.state.pokemon == []) {
                            return '';
                        }else{
                            return(
                                this.state.pokemon.map((item, key) =>{
                                    console.log("item",item.url);
                                    return(
                                        <tr key={key}>
                                            <td>{item.name}</td>
                                            <td><Modal url={item.url}></Modal></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    )
                                }
                                )
                            );
                        }
                    })
                    ()
                }
            </tbody>
```

dentro del modal recibo mi url y la proceso en la siguiente funcion

```
detail(){
axios.get(this.state.url)
.then(res =>{
    const detail = res.data.abilities;
    this.setState({detail});
})
```

}

Este es el codigo del componente modal:

```
<div>
        <a className="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light modal-trigger" data-target="modal1"><i className="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    <div
      ref={Modal => {
        this.Modal = Modal;
      }}
      id="modal1"
      className="modal"
    >
      <div className="modal-content">
                    <img id="titulo" src={title}></img>
                    <img id="ball" src={logo}></img>
          <table >
              <tr>
                <th>Abilities</th>
                <th>Effects</th>
              </tr>
              {
                  (()=>{
                      if (this.state.detail === undefined) {
                          return '';
                      }else{
                          return(
                            this.state.detail.map((item, key) =>{
                                return (
                                    <tr key={key}> 
                                        <td>{item.ability.name}</td>
                                        <td>
                                        <div className="panel-group">
                                            <div className="panel panel-default">
                                            <div className="panel-heading">
                                                <h4 className="panel-title">
                                                <a onClick={(e)=>this.collapseEffects(e, item.ability.url, key)} className="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light"><i className="material-icons">pageview</i></a>
                                                </h4>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                            <div className={this.state.open && this.state.keycollapse === key ? "panel-collapse": "panel-collapse panel-close"}>
                                                                                                
                                            <ul className="list-group">
                                                    {
                                                                    this.state.effect.map((i,keys)=>{
                                                                      return(
                                                                        <React.Fragment>
                                                                          <li className="list-group-item">{i.effect}</li>
                                                                          <div className="dividerpkm"></div>
                                                                        </React.Fragment>
                                                                      );
                                                                    })                                                               
                                                    }
                                                    </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                );
                            
                            }
                            )
                          );
                      }
                  })
                    ()
                }
          </table>
      </div>
      <div className="modal-footer">
        <a className="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">
          Close
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

No se por que siempre me manda la url del primer elemento.

Comment: Podrías mostrar la función de tu botón?

Comment: El boton esta dentro del componente modal solo tiene la llamada al modal `<a className="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light modal-trigger" data-target="modal1"><i className="material-icons">menu</i></a>`